# OpenGL - Unwanted z axis camera rotation

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

When I rotate my camera on the X axis while the Y rotation is > or < than 0, it also rotates the Z axis.
Why does it do this?

```
if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP)){
    xRot-=speed_rotation;
    glRotatef(-speed_rotation, 1, 0, 0);
}
if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_DOWN)){
    xRot+=speed_rotation;
    glRotatef(speed_rotation, 1, 0, 0);
}
if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LEFT)){
    yRot-=speed_rotation;
    glRotatef(-speed_rotation, 0, 1, 0);
}

if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_RIGHT)){
    yRot+=speed_rotation;
    glRotatef(speed_rotation, 0, 1, 0);
}
```

I think I know what is causing it, but I'm not so sure...

Answer (score 2):

Don't `glRotate()` in the keyboard handler, just update the x/y rotation values like you're doing and issue a *single* set of `glRotate()s` just before you draw.